# setting a footer to the contents or pages end

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm looking for a possibility to set the footer to the end of my page or the end of my content if the content is greater than one page.
I do not want to have a fixed footer where the content is scrollable.
I do not know whether it is possible.

So, this is my code.
The div with class="div1" contains the content.
The content contains the content as well as the footer.

```
<div class="div1">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="myContent"></div>
      <div class="myContent"></div>
      <div class="myContent"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The footer has a height of 50px.
My problem is following:
If I have a screen height with height:500px and the content is only 150px high, the footer is set after the last div-element with class="myContent".
It should be set to the end of the page like the effect I receive with

```
bottom:0;position:fixed
```

But if the content is 600px high the footer should be set right after the last div with class="myContent". No styles would be needed here.

Have you got an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean [Make the Footer Stick to the Bottom of a Page](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) ? 
or this [one](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

the css

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 150px;
clear:both;}
```

and the html

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm late. Unfortunately my html is different. :-( The footer div is in the main div. Your example doesn't work in my case...that was the reason why I was asking.

Comment: then move your footer out of the main or create a new div. you know this is an example you need to alter it to feet your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you get rid off this problem:

```
.footer {position:absolute;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:green;height:50px}
```

This may solve the objective:

```
<div style="position:absolute">
    <div style="position:absolute">
        <div id="top" style="height:50px;width:100%;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background:red"> content 1 </div>
        <div id="middle" style="background:green;position:fixed;top:50px; left:0;bottom:50px;right:0">content 2 </div>
        <div id="middle" style="background:blue;position:fixed;top:100px; left:0;bottom:50px;right:0">content 3 </div>
        <div id="bottom" style="height:50px;width:100%;position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;background:orange">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work because someone already set the position:absolute in the parents divs - somewhere. Thank you anyway. It was worth a try.

Comment: @judi55 Hi mate, Check the new answer. It will work I think. If not please comment me what's the problem. Here I use `position:absolute` for all parent `div`. If any one `div` has `position:absolute` this will also work I think.